# Adding TSL To Mongo causes it to crash

Tags: mongodb, tls1.2

I have a 3 mongodb replication architecture up and running.  When I add TSL to the /etc/mongod conf file mongod it crashes right away and writes nothing to mongo log.  I put the pem file containing all the certs and key in /etc/ssl/mongo.pem with the key at the bottom of the file.  I did a chmod 600 on the pem file.  I am adding TSL to the primary first and stopping and starting mongod.  My mongod TLS config:

```
net:

  port: 27017

  bindIpAll: true

  tls:

    mode: requireTLS

    certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
security:
  keyFile: /opt/mongod/keyfile
```

The error I get when starting:

```
ec2-user@ip-10-0-16-140 log]$ sudo service mongod start
Starting mongod (via systemctl):  Job for mongod.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mongod.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
                                                           [FAILED]
```

The return from the status call:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-16-140 ~]$ systemctl status mongod.service
● mongod.service - SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database.
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod; bad; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-02-28 00:43:51 UTC; 17s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 18327 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 18548 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/mongod start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal runuser[18559]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal runuser[18559]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal mongod[18548]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-16-140 ~]$ journalctl -xe
Feb 28 00:42:13 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18523]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 00:42:27 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18525]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/vi /etc/mongo.pem
Feb 28 00:42:27 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18525]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ec2-user(uid=0)
Feb 28 00:42:31 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18525]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 00:42:38 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18527]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/vi /etc/ssl/mongo.pem
Feb 28 00:42:38 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18527]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ec2-user(uid=0)
Feb 28 00:43:38 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18527]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18529]: ec2-user : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/ec2-user ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/sbin/service mongod start
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18529]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ec2-user(uid=0)
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Starting SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database....
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has begun starting up.
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal runuser[18559]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session opened for user mongod by (uid=0)
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal runuser[18559]: pam_unix(runuser:session): session closed for user mongod
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal mongod[18548]: Starting mongod: [FAILED]
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start SYSV: Mongo is a scalable, document-oriented database..
-- Subject: Unit mongod.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mongod.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal sudo[18529]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Feb 28 00:43:51 ip-10-0-16-140.us-gov-east-1.compute.internal dhclient[2603]: XMT: Solicit on eth0, interval 113300ms.
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be an issue with your `mongodb.pem` file. For testing purposes, you can create a self-signed certificate and key like this:

```
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -new -x509 -days 365 -nodes -out mongodb-cert.crt -keyout mongodb-cert.key

cat mongodb-cert.key mongodb-cert.crt > mongodb.pem
```

and then set the permissions on the PEM file, you can use

```
chmod 600 mongodb.pem
```

consider the following configuration file for a mongod instance:

```
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: 0.0.0.0
   port: 27017
```

Note: bindIP with `0.0.0.0` is not best practice, but it good place to start 
Also, you may find logs in  `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log` as the default path

Comment: I did as recommended and mongod still crashes.  I do not get anything written to the mongo log.  It is almost as if the syntax in the mongod.conf causes it to crash even though I took the entry straight from the MongoDB SSL documentation.

Comment: net:

   tls:

      mode: requireTLS

      certificateKeyFile: /etc/ssl/mongodb.pem

systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
storage:
   dbPath: "/var/lib/mongodb"
processManagement:
   fork: true
net:
   bindIp: localhost,mongodb0.example.net
   port: 27017

Comment: You should see errors on logs unless you have wrong permission or wrong config